# Daily active users count in range

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb for saving messages.
Messages saved in this format

```
{
    userId: String,
    date: Date,
    message: String
}
```

Now I want to get all daily active users Ids in range. I want to do it only with aggregate. Can anyone say me most elegant way to do aggregation like this, and it must work as fast as possible.

The first Idea that comes on my mind is group all messages by day of date and get usersIds for all days, then with loop filter daily active users, but it is not good way and will work slow. Problem is that I dont want to do anything without aggregate. So aggregate must return something like this

```
{
    dayOfYear: Number,
    users: [ String ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the fastest way to fix your problem:

```
db.gor.aggregate([{
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    year : {
                        $year : "$date"
                    },
                    dayOfYear : {
                        $dayOfYear : "$date"
                    }
                },
                users : {
                    $addToSet : "$userId"
                }
            }
        }

])
```

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Thank you, not bad, but then you need to write js code, for getting all users which messaged every dat. So I dont want to write js code, I solved it but I not sure it is best way, please check my answer

Comment: you question is not well formulated. your answer will produce slightly different  output that provided by you as expected ;-). So we have SISO processing here...

Answer (score 0):

```
    var range = Math.abs(from.getTime() - to.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(range / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) - 1;
    Messages.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: {
                    incoming: true,
                    date: {
                        $gte: from,
                        $lte: to
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        sender: "$sender"
                    },
                    days: {
                        $addToSet: { $dayOfYear: "$date" }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    days: 1
                    daysCount: { $size: "$days" }
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    daysCount: { $gte: diffDays }
                }
            }
        ],
        (err, res) => {
            if(err) {
                return emitter.sendNativeError(err);
            }

            return emitter.sendData({users: res});
        }
    );
```